# Data validation rule is not working with query(importrange in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, checkbox, google-sheets

I'm importing data from one spreadsheet to another one: my formula `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE` is in C9. Everything is working except my script regarding a data validation rule. **I want a checkbox to appear in column B any time there is a data in column C.**

```
function createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   ScriptApp.newTrigger('onChange')
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
    .onOpen()
    .create();

function onChange(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

 // When a PO number is filled in Col8 or H, generate the data validation for the row   
  var lastRow = s.getLastRow();
  var listRange1 = ss.getSheetByName('Settings').getRange('B3:B7'); // list range for Factor Status
  var listRange2 = ss.getSheetByName('Settings').getRange('C3:C8'); // list range for Payment Status
    if (s.getName() == "2019-2020" && r.getRow() == lastRow && r.getColumn() == 8){
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox().build()
    s.getRange(lastRow,2).setDataValidation(rule); // rule to create the check box data validation in Col2 or B
    var rule1 = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(listRange1).build()
    s.getRange(lastRow,17).setDataValidation(rule1); // rule to create drop down list for Factor Status in Col17
    var rule2 = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(listRange2).build()
    s.getRange(lastRow,16).setDataValidation(rule2); // rule to create drop down list for Payment Status in Col16
  }
 }
}
```

If I add manually content in column C, the script works. But **it doesn't work for the imported data**. Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: ImportRange does not trigger onEdit

Comment: The only thing that triggers an onEdit is a user edit.

Answer (score 0):

### `IMPORTRANGE` does not trigger `onEdit`, but it triggers on `onChange`

- `onChange` is an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- Rename your function and bind the `onChange` trigger to it
- This should run your function each time there is an update in the imported range

Comment: Hello ziganotschka! I didn't had time to look at it yet but I'll be back to you when I try to change my script with your recommendations. Thank you for your help, again.

Comment: Hello ziganotschka, I created a OnChange trigger for the spreadsheet I'm editing (edit access), I'm running the script (I've changed the OnEdit by OnChange) but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Maybe it is because I'm using an arrayformula for the imported data?
`=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(LEN({ IF(LEN(Treatment!$H$9:$H); "♣"&Treatment!$H$9:$H&"♣"&Treatment!$I$9:$I&"♣"&Treatment!$J$9:$J;)...`

Comment: It seems like you are not using `importrange()`?

Comment: You are right, I had to change since my post how to do it: I needed to find a formula to do a treatment of the database. So I'm importing through `Query(Importrange` the data from another spreadsheet; and then I had to use an `arrayformula` because I wanted to transpose the data into rows... sorry I forgot to mention this update

Comment: Unfortunately only `IMPORTRANGE` will fire the `onChange` trigger. As a workaround, you can create a secondary spreadsheet into which you import with `IMPORTRANGE` the range that contains your arrayformula.

Comment: Good tip, just created. But something is probably missing because it doesn't still working... I've installed the trigger through the code I've updated in my post. Thank for your help by the way

Comment: Hello ziganotschka, I spent all day on checking about the OnChange trigger, I've executed my script many times (which has a completed status), I've tried to install and reinstall the trigger, I tested it, but I still don't have the checkbox or drop-down list in my sheet I duplicated under an importrange as you suggested it. Can you help me again please?

Comment: If you can provide a sample sheet, I can have a look why it doe not work.

Comment: Thank you for your help ziganotschka, here's the public link with an edit access. The script is saved in the script editor.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OJZoM4hlLnexBnf8sGjSX0omFPWiP4pp3CAETVFFA68/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Two problems: 1. Your `if` condition: `onChange` fires the trigger, but it will not make `2019-2020` the active sheet, nor the new PO No the active cell. Query instead: `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("2019-2020"); if (!sheet.getRange(lastRow, 8).isBlank()){...` 2. You have many empty rows that propagate through `importrange` and `arrayformula` from sheet to sheet. `getLastRow()` won't work correctly until you get rid of them.